# Quick Big Oh calculation

Tags: big-o

I'm reviewing Big Oh notation. Is there such a thing as big oh order function: O(n * (n/2)) ? I just assumed that it would just be O(n^2) but these notes say differently (not my notes). The notes are referring to this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < x/2; j++)
    {
        halfsum += a[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In big-O notation it's true that O(n^2) = O(n^2 / 2), so of course O(n^2 / 2) exists, it's just a bit pointless to state the constant, so why bother? Its not that it's not correct, just meaningless.

It's just like in simple 6th grade math: X = X * 1. There's not point in writing down multiplication by 1, but it's not erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

You drop the coefficient so technically that is still O(n^2).
In other words O((n^2)/2) = O(n^2).